# SQL Server 2008: Return users in DISTINCT Group

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a `Group` table setup as follows

```
GroupID  InActive  Name
G1       0         Person1
G2       0         Person2
G3       0         Person1
G1       1         Person3
G2       0         Person4
G4       0         Person4
```

I don't know up front how many GroupIDs there are or what they are called or how many Names there are or what they are called.

I am looking to get a list of each person in each distinct group (who does not have an `IsActive` state of 1) in a table like this

```
G1       G2       G3       G4       etc...
Person1  Person2  Person1  Person4
         Person4
```

Is this at all possible? I only have `SELECT` access to the database so creating temporary tables etc is out.

Thanks for looking,

DT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example script that pivots the data the way you want it. What it does:

1. Create temporary table `#t` with the sample data you gave
2. Determine the GroupID's to pivot dynamically in `@GroupIDCols`
3. Determine the GroupID's to select dynamically in `@GroupIDSel`
4. Pivots the data in `#t`. First a row number is assigned to the rows in `#t` to distinguish between persons for a certain GroupID (see derived table `t`). Then [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is used on the derived table to get the result you want.

The script:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(
    GroupID CHAR(2),
    InActive BIT,
    Name VARCHAR(16)
);

INSERT INTO #t
    (GroupID,InActive,Name)
VALUES
    ('G1',0,'Person1'),
    ('G2',0,'Person2'),
    ('G3',0,'Person1'),
    ('G1',1,'Person3'),
    ('G2',0,'Person4'),
    ('G4',0,'Person4');

DECLARE @GroupIDCols VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @GroupIDCols=STUFF(
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        ','+QUOTENAME(GroupID)
    FROM
        #t
    WHERE
        InActive=0
    FOR 
        XML PATH('')    
    )
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);

DECLARE @GroupIDSel VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @GroupIDSel=STUFF(
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        ',COALESCE('+QUOTENAME(GroupID)+','''') AS '+QUOTENAME(GroupID)
    FROM
        #t
    WHERE
        InActive=0
    FOR 
        XML PATH('')    
    )
    ,1
    ,1
    ,''
);


DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @query='
    SELECT
        '+@GroupIDSel+'
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                GroupID,
                Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY Name) AS rn
            FROM
                #t
            WHERE
                InActive=0
        ) AS t
        PIVOT(
            MAX(Name)
            FOR GroupID IN ('+@GroupIDCols+')
        ) AS piv
';

EXEC (@query);

DROP TABLE #t;
```

The result:

```
G1      G2      G3      G4
Person1 Person2 Person1 Person4
        Person4
```

Comment: Wow I do not understand that in the slightest but it looks good!

Comment: @D_T To better understand, it might help to print out each substep so you get a better insight into how the query is built. For instance do a `PRINT @query` after the `@query` variable was built, and format it in a SQL formatter (eg [this one](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)). That way you see what the actual query looks like. You can also print the `@GroupIDCols` to get the column specification of the PIVOT clause, and `@GroupIDSel` to see the selected columns of the SELECT statement.